# If $A_1, A_2, ...$ is a list of countable sets, then$A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 ...$ is also countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Does anyone know the reasoning behind the diagonal ordering in the second picture?  I have seen it before, but am not sure what it's showing relating to this proof.

[image: a]

[image: b]

Comment: You can't prove this in ZF. You need something like axiom of choice for this to hold.

Comment: $AC$ or weaker $AC_\omega$ seems to be hidden in the choices of enumeration of the sets: $A_i=\{a_{i1},a_{i2},a_{i3},\ldots\}$ (i.e. for every $i$ we choose one *particular* enumeration out of all enumerations available), rather than in the "diagonal" construction that follows. See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2966801/700480

Comment: Yes you need AC for the theorem because you need to choose enumerations of all the $A_i$ to build the matrix. The zig-zag enumeration of the matrix is definable without AC.

Comment: I'm confused why the diagonal construction was used to "make a list that contains all the above lists".  What property does this diagonal construction have that it is used in the proof?

Comment: @Nick It collects every element of every list exactly once, in effect turning the union of all those lists into *one* big list. Any other construction that would do the same would be just as good. Will edit my answer to say that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need any reason further than just "it does the job!"? (It collects every element of every list exactly once, in effect turning the union of all those lists into *one* big list. Any other construction that would do the same would be just as good.)

I think that this example shows where our finite set intuition breaks when you switch to infinite sets.

If there were $n$ sets with $n$ elements each (with $n$ finite), you could use the same procedure, but much more likely you would go row-by-row or column-by-column.

Here you cannot do *either* because you can never enumerate the first row and switch to the second one (let alone third, fourth etc. - and similar for columns) so, somehow enumerating rows and columns "at the same time" is the only thing that can work.